# Runnning ruby script with 'require "google/cloud/storage" '

Tags: rubygems, google-cloud-storage

I run ruby script with google-cloud-storage gem
and specified 'require "google/cloud/storage" '
Then I had below error:
/Users/yuujifujita/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/specification.rb:2317:in `raise_if_conflicts': Unable to activate google-cloud-translate-v2-0.4.1, because faraday-2.9.0 conflicts with faraday (>= 0.17.3, < 2.a) (Gem::ConflictError)

Anything wrong with my gem setup?
I did not use google-cloud-translate-v2-0.4.1, while I am using google translate in other ruby coding.

Let me know how I can fix this

How I can fix this?